# NodeJS: add options to npmrc

Tags: node.js

I am currently running my script as

```
node --no-deprecation main.js
```

I was wondering if there is a way to add this option to `~/.npmrc` or otherwise (environment variable), such that I do not need to add the option to the command line. I would like to just run my script as `node main.js` and to be shown no deprecation warnings.

To make this question more general, is there a general way in NodeJS of setting flag values in a config file rather than adding it to the command (say I am interested in running with `--trace-warnings` as well.

I am looking for something cleaner than say `alias node="node --no-deprecation"`.

I already tried adding this line inside `~/.npmrc`

```
no-deprecationss=true
```

Reference:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_no_deprecation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a global configuration, setting the `--no-deprecation` flag in the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable in your `.bashrc` or other shell config file is what you're looking for, as long as you're using node v8 or above.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via package.json. e.g

```
 "scripts": {
    "main": "node --no-deprecation main.js"
 },
```

and run it via

```
npm run main
```

or

```
yarn main
```

Comment: Thank you! While a valid solution, this is project specific and I would have to do it for each and every project. I was looking more for a global setting that I can activate (like an env variable that I can set in my bashrc or a setting somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone new who comes across it, one reproducible way to do this without having to add it to every npm script and without affecting other projects (which is what would happen if you added it to `.bashrc` or `.profile`), is to add a `.npmrc` file in your project with `node-options` set in it.

It accepts the same flags as [NODE_OPTIONS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options) except applied to every npm script in your project without affecting others and keeping your scripts DRY.

e.g.

```sh
# Sets the flags in NODE_OPTIONS when running `npm run myScript`
node-options='--no-deprecation'
```